# MVC - Conditionally using action based on object type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a View that is displaying data from a list of object that I send it.  These objects are all the same base class, but can be a number of different derived types.  so, I have:

```
class Item { public string Description {get;set;}
class VideoItem : Item { public int VideoId {get;set;} }
class PdfItem : Item { public pdfLocation {get;set;} }
```

I display these all in a single list and would like to be able to have one Controller Method that I can call that will handle each one of these.  Having overloads for the method would be fine as well.

I have it wired in as an ActionLink, but I can't figure out how to pass the entire object to the controller.  When I try to pass the class, it only passes the classname (i'm assuming it's using the .ToString() method on it.

I could use some sort of unique id and then requery the database and recreate the object, but it seems that if I already created the object, I should be able to pass it to a controller intact, no?

Maybe ActionLink isn't the best solution.  I dont care how the controller gets called.

ideas?

Comment: Post more code please. Show your controller and view as well.

Comment: ActionLink is HTTP Get, all of your data would have to be part of the query string. The easiest method would be to overload the ToString method on each of your classes to generate string equal to what a querystring would be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this can work for you (assuming you want to display the content of each item as a link):

Create a custom HtmlHelper method:

```
public static class LinkExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Item item )
    {
        MvcHtmlString returnString = "";

        if(item is VideoItem) 
        {
            VideoItem currentItem = item as VideoItem;
            returnString = htmlHelper.ActionLink(currentItem.VideoId, "Video", "Item");
        }        
        if(item is PdfItem) 
        {
            PdfItem currentItem = item as PdfItem;
            returnString = htmlHelper.ActionLink(currentItem.pdfLocation, "Pdf", "Item");
        }
        else
        {
            returnString = htmlHelper.ActionLink(currentItem.Description, "Item", "Item");
        }

        return returnString;
    }
}
```

Use it like this (assuming itemList is a `List<Item>` type list):

```
<%= foreach(var item in itemList) { Html.CustomActionLink(item) } %>
```

NOTE: i did not run this code so some tweaking may be necessary.

Comment: using this same idea you could use an interface so the objects don't even have to be of the same base type

Comment: This isn't really what I was expecting, but it will work perfectly.  Thanks.. I'm marking you as the answer, and I'll post my final solution once it's done.